# Memory Leak in Matlab when calling a C++ mexfile

Tags: c++, matlab, memory-leaks, mex

Dear stackoverflow community,

I am currently working on a MEX function that itself calls external C++ code.
I am calling my MEX in a loop.
Here is my mexfile:

```
#include "mex.h"
#include "OOMP.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

/*
function [h, Di, beta, c, Q, NorQ] = OOMP_v4(f, D, tol,ind,No)
%OOMP Optimized Orthogonal Matching Pursuit
%
% It creates an atomic decomposition of a siganl
% using OOMP criterion. You can choose a  tolerance,
% the number of atoms to take in or an initial subspace to influence the OOMP algorithm.
%
%
% Usage:    [h, Di, c, beta, Q, NorQ ] = OOMP_v2(f, D, tol,ind, No);
%           [h, Di, c] = OOMP_v2(f, D, tol,ind, No);
*/
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[] , int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{

    /* Begin input validation */
    if(nrhs != 5)
    {
        mexErrMsgTxt("Wrong number of input arguments");
    }
    // Check we are being passed real full and non string variables
   for ( int i = 0; i < nrhs; i++ )
    {
        if ( mxIsComplex(prhs[i]) || mxIsClass(prhs[i],"sparse") || mxIsChar(prhs[i]) || !mxIsDouble(prhs[i]) )
        {
            mexErrMsgTxt("Input must be double, real, full,and nonstring");
        }
    }
    // First check f is a vector
    if ((mxGetM(prhs[0]) !=1) || (mxGetN(prhs[0]) == 1))
    {
        mexErrMsgTxt("f should be a line vector");
    }
    // Validate D
    if ( (mxGetM(prhs[1])) != (mxGetN(prhs[0])) )
    {
        mexPrintf("The atoms in the dictionary D are of length %i and should be of length %i\n",mxGetM(prhs[1]),mxGetN(prhs[0]));
        mexErrMsgTxt("Error!!\n");
    }
    if ((mxGetM(prhs[1])) == 1)
    {
        mexErrMsgTxt("The dictionary D should contain more than 1 atom!!\n");
    }
    long L = mxGetM(prhs[1]);
    long N = mxGetN(prhs[1]);
    long numInd = mxGetN(prhs[3]);

    Matrix *f = new Matrix(mxGetPr(prhs[0]),1,L, 'T');
    Matrix *D = new Matrix(mxGetPr(prhs[1]),L,N,'T');

    double tol = mxGetScalar(prhs[2]);
    Matrix *mind = new Matrix(mxGetPr(prhs[3]),1,numInd);
    long No = mxGetScalar(prhs[4]);

    /* Begin Output validation */

    if ( nlhs <3 || nlhs >6)
    {
        mexErrMsgTxt("Wrong number of output arguments");
    }
        Matrix *h = new Matrix(1,L,0);
        Matrix *Di= new Matrix(1,0,0);
        Matrix *beta= new Matrix(L,0,0);
        Matrix *c= new Matrix(1,0,0);
        Matrix *Q= new Matrix(L,0,0);
        Matrix *NorQ= new Matrix((long)0,1,0);

        int fail =OOMP_v4(f,D,tol,mind,No ,L, N,h,Di,beta,c,Q,NorQ);

    if(!fail)
    {
        // Creation des variables de Sorties
        long K = (*Di).getNbre_C();
        plhs[0] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,L,mxREAL);
        plhs[1] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,K,mxREAL);
        plhs[2] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(1,K,mxREAL);
        if(nlhs>=4)
            plhs[3] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(L,K,mxREAL);
        if(nlhs>=5)
            plhs[4] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(L,K,mxREAL);
        if(nlhs==6)
            plhs[5] = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(K,1,mxREAL);

         // Transformation
        double *m_h= mxGetPr(plhs[0]);
        double *m_Di = mxGetPr(plhs[1]);
        double *m_c = mxGetPr(plhs[2]);

        ToArray(h,m_h,1,L);
        ToArray(Di,m_Di,1,K);
        ToArray(c,m_c,1,K);

        if(nlhs>=4){
            double *m_beta = mxGetPr(plhs[3]);
            ToArray(beta,m_beta,L,K);
        }
        if(nlhs>=5){
            double *m_Q = mxGetPr(plhs[4]);
            ToArray(Q,m_Q,L,K);
        }
        if(nlhs==6){
            double *m_NorQ = mxGetPr(plhs[5]);
            ToArray(NorQ,m_NorQ,K,1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
         mexErrMsgTxt("Error OOMP exited early see message above!!\n");
    }
}
```

I am using the previous mexfile in a matlab program that runs successfully

Here is the loop using the mexfile:

```
for i=1:Nframes
f=F(:,i)'; %the signals are the colums of F
tol=PRD0*norm(f)/100; 
[h, Di0, ~] = OOMP_for_new_Mex(f, D, tol,ind,No); 
error_norm(i)= norm(f-h);
K(i)=numel(Di0);
clear Di0  h f tol ;
end
```

I got good results but the program is using too much memory 10Gb! which awkward because the variable stocked in the Matlab use only a few Mb.
The problem here that in each loop new memory is allocated but it is not released in the end of the loop: The pointers created in the mex file are not deleted after every iteration.

So my questions are:

1)Do you see something else that could cause a memory leak in the code?

2)how can I fix it?

Comment: Where do you call `delete` on the memory you allocated with `new`? Memory allocated with `new` is never released automatically in C++. You must call `delete` on it manually. Is it really necessary to use `new` here at all? Would automatic storage duration not do? (Note that I don't know about Matlab or the library/tool used. The C++ code just looks suspect from a pure C++ perspective.)

Comment: In the matrix class I am defining a destructor . It is not called automatically in the end of the c++ file ?

Comment: No, not when you use dynamic memory allocation with `new` for the objects. Their destructor is called and their memory released only if you explicitly `delete` them. If you use automatic storage duration objects, then their destructor will be called and their memory released once their scope is left. This is why I am wondering what made you feel the need to use `new`.

Comment: Thank you very much! The problem is solved.

Comment: Instead of `Matrix *h = new Matrix(1,L,0);` do `Matrix h(1,L,0);`, and then use `&h` if you need to pass a pointer. This way it will be automatically deleted when `h` goes out of scope. You should try really hard to not use `new` in C++, it is hardly ever really necessary. Naked `new` is hard, the matching `delete` could be skipped, for example if an exception is thrown somewhere. If you really need a heap-allocated object for some reason, use a `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr`.